# onPostExecute() not executing in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am trying to create an activity that allows a user to login by checking the username and password from a database, however after the creadentials are fetched successfully, the doInbackground doesnt stop executing.I not sure what i can do to make the onpostexecute to run. Here is the code

```
 public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

public String username;
public String password;
public String userid;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    Button loginbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);

    final EditText usernameText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameInput);
    final EditText passwordText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInput);

    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            username=usernameText.getText().toString();
            password=passwordText.getText().toString();

            if(username.trim().length()==0 || password.trim().length()==0){
                AlertDialogManager diag=new AlertDialogManager();
                diag.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(), "Fill Fields", "enter a username and password", false);


            }else{
                //send the username and password for verification
                new Login().execute();

            }


        }
    });


}
//http class starts here.
class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/newptk/dalvik/auth.php";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("Auth", "working");
        JSONArray document = null;
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", params);

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        SessionManager smg=new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        int flag = 0;
        try {
            flag = json.getInt("success");

            if(flag==1){
                userid=json.getString("userid");
                //set the session 
                smg.createLoginSession(username, userid);   
                //Login the user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportFound.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }else{
                AlertDialogManager diag=new AlertDialogManager();
                diag.showAlertDialog(LoginActivity.this, "Login", "Incorrect Username/password", false);
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}//end of http class
```

}

Comment: have you tried debugging the code to see where the doInBackground stops?

Comment: It doesn't look as though you are overriding the appropriate onPostExecute().  You have just defined one yourself that won't get called.  Try and use auto-complete for onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you are telling `onPostExecute()` to accept a `String` in your class header

```
class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

but aren't accepting anything or passing anything to it

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
```

if you don't want to pass it anything then change it to

```
class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
...
}

@Override
protected void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
```

Notice this section in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> **The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:**
>
> Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
>
> Progress, the type of the progress units published during the
>   background computation.
>
> Result, the type of the result of the
>   background computation.
>
> Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` will be called no matter what the parameter types are... correct?

Comment: @AlexLockwood not if the parameters don't match up what's in the class header and in the method headers...I don't believe. If it does get called then there are going to be errors/exceptions

Comment: @AlexLockwood If you aren't overriding the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask class, then you are just creating an instance of it yourself that won't get called.  Which is what he is trying to point out as a possible error.

Comment: @AlexLockwood when doinbackground() finishes onPostExecute() is invoked. Unless you have a crash yes it is invoked.

Comment: Yes, I was going to point out the missing override but I was trying to figure out the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
protected void onPostExecute()
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
```

and you should be golden. Consider adding `@Override` tags in your code to prevent these subtle bugs in the future.